# Search modules for play framework 2

Tags: lucene, playframework-2.0, elasticsearch

I'm currently exploring Play framework 2 and I must say that I'm impressed!
There is only one thing that I can't rap my head around(for the moment) and
that is the search implementations.

Currently I have found:
[search module](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/search) and [elastic search](http://www.playframework.org/modules/elasticsearch) but both are for Play 1

Do they work in Play 2?

I'm coming from Spring and Seam world where Hibernate Search is pretty common.
Is there an implementation for that? How do you Play 2 guys implement
your search functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is not any core module for full text search in Play 2.0

There is an project on GitHub which incorporates ElasticSearch to Play 1.x: https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch.

There is also sample how to update ES after each Ebean operation on Play 2.0: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/cZqt6U-2LHg%5B1-25%5D

Comment: Ok. Have you used any other search while developing in Play 2.0?

Comment: Nope, but I plan to use one, so I am interest on any feedback on the subject :-)

Comment: @jakob, nico_ekito, I found module for Play 2 for ElasticSearch, check pls edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Postgres full text indexes if you are already using a relational database (mysql 5.6 full text doesn't handle stemming but it might work for your needs too). If the database you are already using anyway does what you need, it is very convenient to not have to sync/manage more stack complexity.